# Golang code panics with runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go

I have this piece of Golang microservice code that when it is called, panics with error "**panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference**".

here is the code:

```
type DBserver struct {
    protoc.UnimplementedUserManagementServer
    i.DBService
}

func NewDBserver(service i.DBService) *DBserver {
    return &DBserver{
        DBService: service,
    }
}

func (ds *DBserver) Listen(address string) {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", address)
    if err != nil {
        //TODO: log properly (main logger file)
        log.Fatalf("could not listen to tcp conn port :%s : %s", address, err)
    }
    ServerRegistrar := grpc.NewServer()

    protoc.RegisterUserManagementServer(ServerRegistrar, &DBserver{})
    if err := ServerRegistrar.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        //TODO: log properly (main logger file)
        log.Fatalf("could not serve grpc :%s", err)
    }
}

func (ds *DBserver) SaveUser(ctx context.Context, u *protoc.User) (*protoc.DBresponse, error) {

    User := modals.User{
        Fname:     u.Fname,
        Mname:     u.Mname,
        Lname:     u.Lname,
        Username:  u.Username,
        Password:  u.Password,
        Contact:   int(u.Contact),
        Email:     u.Email,
        Sex:       u.Sex,
        Role:      int(u.Role),
        CreatedBy: u.CreatedBy,
    }
    log.Printf("calling DB to create user:\n %v", User)

    createdID, err := ds.DBService.Users("create", User)
    if err != nil {
        return &protoc.DBresponse{
            Success: false,
            ID:      "",
        }, err
    }
    return &protoc.DBresponse{
        Success: true,
        ID:      createdID,
    }, nil
}
```

When I run the service, I'm facing the issue below:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x7b89be]

goroutine 9 [running]:
github.com/tazafrosoul/school-system/db-manager/transport/grpc.(*DBserver).SaveUser(0xc000022bf0, {0xc0001ee0f0?, 0x4f2966?}, 0x0?)
        /home/taz/projects/go/src/github.com/tazafrosoul/school-system/db-manager/transport/grpc/dbserver.go:56 +0x11e
github.com/tazafrosoul/school-system/common/grpc/protoc._UserManagement_SaveUser_Handler({0x8328e0?, 0xc000022bf0}, {0x947788, 0xc0001d6b70}, 0xc0001cc580, 0x0)
        /home/taz/projects/go/src/github.com/tazafrosoul/school-system/common/grpc/protoc/dbmgr_grpc.pb.go:79 +0x169
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC(0xc0001f8200, {0x947788, 0xc0001d6ae0}, {0x94a738, 0xc000228000}, 0xc0001b3200, 0xc0001d64e0, 0xc2c3c0, 0x0)
        /home/taz/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.60.1/server.go:1372 +0xe03
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream(0xc0001f8200, {0x94a738, 0xc000228000}, 0xc0001b3200)
        /home/taz/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.60.1/server.go:1783 +0xfec
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func2.1()
        /home/taz/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.60.1/server.go:1016 +0x59
created by google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func2 in goroutine 8
        /home/taz/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.60.1/server.go:1027 +0x115
exit status 2
```

What might be the issue here?

I tried removing this 56th line that calls database i.e: `createdID, err := ds.DBService.Users("create", User)`
When I mock variables and run it, now the code runs just fine.

Comment: are you calling `NewDBserver` before `SaveUser`?

Comment: Have you tried running this in a debugger? Set a breakpoint to the line before the error happens and then trigger it.

Comment: Didn't you mean `protoc.RegisterUserManagementServer(ServerRegistrar, ds)` instead of `protoc.RegisterUserManagementServer(ServerRegistrar, &DBserver{})`?

Comment: @rdleal, you're  real deal. That was exactly my problem. Have a beer wherever you are man, i'll pay :D

Comment: Hi @MariaInesParnisari, yes I am calling `NewDBserver` in the main function.

Comment: Hello @UlrichEckhardt, I have tried the debugger brother and i couldn't understand nothing. Perhaps I was looking at the wrong breakpoint but the debugger was jumping into std and third part packages code, I am still learning this debugging thing to check only my code base callstack. Thanks for the idea anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what would happen if you run:

```
x := &DBserver{}
createdID, err := x.DBService.Users("create", User)
```

As no value is provided for the embedded `i.DBService` in `DBserver`, it will default to `nil` (I'm assuming it's an `interface`). So calling `x.DBService.Users` is effectively `nil.Users` hence the panic.

Your code is doing the same thing with:

```
protoc.RegisterUserManagementServer(ServerRegistrar, &DBserver{})
```

The gRPC lib will call `SaveUser` on the `&DBserver{}` you passed in. `SaveUser` then attempts to call `ds.DBService.Users` which will panic because `DBService` is `nil`.

The simplest fix is probably to use `NewDBserver` e.g. `protoc.RegisterUserManagementServer(ServerRegistrar,  NewDBserver(yourDbService))` (obviously you need an `i.DBService`)

** Update - triggered by comment from @rdleal

In the above suggested fix I missed the fact that `protoc.RegisterUserManagementServer(ServerRegistrar, &DBserver{})` is being called in a method of `DBserver`; so you already have a `DBserver` (which I assume is valid) and can just use that:

```
protoc.RegisterUserManagementServer(ServerRegistrar, ds)
```

Comment: oh shoot!! how could i've missed that

Answer (score 1):

so as @Brits and @rdeal pointed out, the issue with this code was on the line `protoc.RegisterUserManagementServer(ServerRegistrar, &DBserver{})` . It should be `protoc.RegisterUserManagementServer(ServerRegistrar, ds)`. Changed this and everything is working fine now.

Thank you guys, cheers.